# Auto dismiss Apple id verification pop up

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

I am using selenium and Appium for automation tests.
I'm trying to figure out how to auto dismiss the Apple id verification pop up on the ipad and iPhone devices before each test.

I have tried to write

```
iosDriver.SwitchTo().Alert().Dismiss()
```

with no success so far.

I have also seen somthing like

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@XCElementType='XCUIElementTypeButton'][3]")).click();
```

but I do not know how to identify the "not now" button.

```
capabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "iOS");
        capabilities.SetCapability("platformVersion", iosPlatformVersion);
        capabilities.SetCapability("browserName", string.Empty);
        capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", deviceName);
        capabilities.SetCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
        capabilities.SetCapability("bundleId", "com.*****.automation");
        capabilities.SetCapability("udid", iphone_udid);
        capabilities.SetCapability("noReset", "true");
        capabilities.SetCapability("fullReset", "false");
        capabilities.SetCapability("xcodeConfigFile", "/Users/******/Desktop/***.xconfig");
        capabilities.SetCapability("agentPath", "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj");
        capabilities.SetCapability("bootstrapPath", "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent");
        capabilities.SetCapability("startIWDP", true);
        capabilities.SetCapability("autoDismissAlerts", true);
        string pathTo****Ipa = null; pathIpa = string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) ? ipaPath : path1;
        capabilities.SetCapability("app", path);
        //XCUITest
        capabilities.SetCapability("waitForAppScript", "$.delay(5000); $.acceptAlert();");
        IOSDriver<IOSElement> driver = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:****/**/***"), capabilities, new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0));
```

would love to hear from people who succeeded in such cases.

Thasnks in advacne.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to take a screenshot of this popup? Maybe it is not a traditional pop up message.

Comment: I have added a pic to the post. thanks :)

Comment: The screenshot looks like the list of apps on an iPhone, and not a web page. Is this being triggered when launching Safari? Can you edit your question and add the code you use to initialize the web driver object, and all of the code up to the `iosDriver.SwitchTo().Alert().Dismiss()` line? We are missing some context.

Comment: It's a pop up on the iPhone without any relation to web browsers.
The problem is that tests cannot run when this is in the background..
I thought ios driver might fix it. btw there are a lot of classes involved in the creation process so it is kind of difficult to upload the whole code, Ill try to upload the most relevant parts. thanks!

Comment: Ok. Can you please edit your question and post the code for initializing the ios driver?

Comment: At what point in your code does this pop up appear?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://iphone-tricks.com/tutorial/4693-apple-id-verification-popup-how-to-fix

Comment: The pop up is there before the test even begins. the point is that the device isn't at sight distance and tests are sometimes running at night so I am trying to automatically dismiss pop-ups before each test...

Comment: @GregBurghardt I will give this tutorial a shot and update the result.
Thanks

Comment: @AvishaiYaniv **but I do not know how to identify the "not now" button.** you can find this element by accessibility id as "Not Now".

Comment: @GregBurghardt  The problem is that the WebDriverAgent cant load because pop up exists on the screen, therefore the creation of IOSDriver is not completed and the test fails.
I am trying to figure out how to dismiss this pop up even before app lunches

Comment: Try this : `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[translate(@text, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='not now']")).click();`

Comment: @frianH Thanks for commenting.
The problem is I can't use the driver because when trying to create it, it fails... 
I need somehow to create the driver without opening any application' click the pop-up and then open the application.

Answer (score 0):

if you are only concerned for this for iOS you can use `$driver.find_element(name: 'Not Now')`. Just translate from ruby.

alternatively:
`$driver.find_element(predicate: "type='XCUIElementTypeButton' AND name MATCHES[cd] 'Not Now'")` <- also in ruby.

I would really avoid using XPath if you can - it's not going to be consistent in the long run.